# How to open a file in C# using FileOpenDialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am trying to open a file by pressing a button (a label to be more exact but it works just the same way)

For some reason when the FileDialog opens and I select the file and press open it doesnt open the file it only closes the FileDialog

```
private void selectLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    ofd.Filter = "Script files (*.au3)|*.au3";
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
    ofd.Title = ("Select Your Helping Script");


    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        ofd.OpenFile(); //Not sure if there is supposed to be more here
    }
}
```

Comment: yes.. because it returns you the path of the file - its then up to you what you do with it.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the purpose of the FileOpenDialog.

Comment: [This guide might help you understand what `OpenFileDialog` does](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog)

Comment: `ofd.OpenFile();` returns a `Stream` to allow the program to read the file, not to open the file itself for the user to see

Comment: What do you expect to happen after you selected a file?

Answer (score 3):

```
ofd.OpenFile();
```

is returning the content of the file as Stream of bytes like described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you want to open the file like you described it, use

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ofd.FileName);
}
```

So your selected file starts with the associated application.

Answer (score 1):

[`ofd.OpenFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) opens the file selected by the user as a `Stream` that you can use to read from the file.

What you do with that stream depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example, you can read and output all lines:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(ofd.OpenFile()))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = t.ReadLine()) != null)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Or if it is an xml file you can parse it as xml:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using(XmlTextReader t = new XmlTextReader(ofd.OpenFile()))
    {
        while (t.Read())
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.Name}: {t.Value}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFileDialog is not a dialog that opens the file. It only communicates with the operator with a dialog that is commonly shown if a program needs to know what file to open. So it is only a dialog box, not a file opener.

You decide what to do if the user pressed ok or cancel:

```
private void selectLbl_click(object sender, ...)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        ofd.Filter = "Script files (*.au3)|*.au3";
        ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;
        ofd.Title = ("Select Your Helping Script");

        var dlgResult = ofd.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {    // operator pressed OK, get the filename:
             string fullFileName = ofd.FileName;
             ProcessFile(fullFileName);
        }
    }
}


if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ofd.OpenFile(); //Not sure if there is supposed to be more here
}
```

Comment: "The OpenFileDialog is not a dialog that opens the file". That is not true, `OpenFile` does open the file, but returns an opened file stream.